# Como alterar a cor de fundo de um item de lista de um ListView no Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

No Delphi 10 com Firemonkey, em tempo de execução eu preciso que ao clicar em um item de lista de um TListView, a cor de fundo deste item seja alterada e permaneça assim mesmo que eu clique em outro item. Depois, mesmo se clicar em outro item, a cor de fundo deste também será alterada e se manterá dessa forma.

Já vi dizerem para usar o TStyleBook e alterar o estilo dos item do ListView, mas não consegui montar o código para executar em runtime.

Imaginei algo assim, mas não funcionou:

```
procedure TForm1.lvListasItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex: Integer;
  const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
var Obj: TFmxObject;
begin
   Obj := ListView1.FindStyleResource('itembackground');
   if Obj <> nil then
   begin
      TColorObject(Obj).Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
   end;
end;
```

Este código não dá erro, mas não funciona. Além disso eu preciso que seja executada a troca de cor apenas no item clicado.

Answer (score 0):

Olha isso não é possível de ser feito em runtime pois o próprio ListView no FireMonkey não permite que seja feito em runtime apenas em design time você pode alterar o backgroundCollor do listview via StyleBook, mas não da maneira que você quer, só poderia ser feito se o Listview fosse VCL mas FMX não, pelo menos que eu saiba é assim infelizmente. Você pode encontrar mais detalhes [aqui](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.16/topics/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_ListView_Appearance).

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção, se você estiver usando o listview com a propriedade `Appearence = DynamicAppearance` você pode adicionar um  `TImageObjectAppearance` preenchendo toda a linha do listview e aplicar uma imagem de (`1px` x `1px`) com a cor que você deseja

esse é o código do exemplo

evento show do form

```
var
  nitem: TListViewItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to 50 do
    begin
      nitem:= ListView1.Items.Add;

      nitem.Data['image']:= ImageList1.Bitmap(TsizeF.Create(1,1), Random(2));
      nitem.Data['text']:=  'registro'+inttostr(i)
    end;
end;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]